# Determine a number from text string

Tags: java, string, numbers

I want determine `number from specify string`.

Ex: I have many text strings, such as "3.2p" or "3.2px" or "xp3.2" or "p3.2x".

The final result I want is can get number from text in above. Expected result "3.2".

People who know,

Please help me,

Thanks,

Comment: replace all "x"s and all "p"s with ""

Comment: try remove all letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first remove all the non-numeric characters using a regex, then parse what remains.

```
String str = input.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

Float.parseFloat(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this:**

```
String s = "ffffa32.334tccy";
s = s.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

Comment: shouldn't you be escaping the "." ?

Comment: @TheLostMind We are using "." as the meta-character, not the literal decimal point. We want the decimal point to remain.

Comment: @TheLostMind, It should only remove the English alphabet from a string.